# Database get blocked when another tab of same application is open

Tags: indexeddb

When an application storing data through IndexedDB is open in 2 tabs of same browser, and code tries to delete the database through one tab by executing `var dbDeleteRequest = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME, {storage: "temporary"});` then neither `onerror` nor `onsuccess` gets called.

I could figure out that database is in blocked state because application is open in another tab, and I could verify same by listening through `onblocked` event.

As soon as I close my other tab, `onsuccess` event will be fired, so this suggests that database is now not in blocked state.
However even when application is open in both tabs, I could perform select, insert etc. operation which means that database is actually not blocked for everything, but just for version change operations.

I checked and same doesn't happen in case of WebSQL.

Is there any way to handle this situation in IndexedDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation, although not very clear, it has sample code on this issue:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Version_changes_while_a_web_app_is_open_in_another_tab

Comment: I had got this earlier but still I can accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I know this is a necroposting, but this answer is so relevant... Thank you from '23!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but it is difficult to interpret what is your question. What you described appears to be precisely how indexedDB is supposed to operate. If the database is open in multiple tabs (pointing to the same general domain), then the database will fire block events for certain transactions, in order to guarantee data integrity.

In general, read operations cannot modify data so read operations are non blocking. Write operations usually modify data so write operations are usually blocking. The call to a write is still async and non-blocking within the context of the JS engine, but not necessarily within the database layer.

What you are experiencing seems like normal expected behavior to me, and not an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. As per my experience and knowledge till now, since IDB has transactional model, select, update and delete transactions works well even when I open application in 2 tabs and work one by one on them. Only problem I see is database getting blocked when doing version change transaction, which works well in case of WebSQL. So, I am trying to understand if there is some way to counter the same because this works in WebSQL. I am trying to contrast and understand IndexedDB v/s WebSQL because to cover all my client's device I have to cover both.